# Writing a function to find multiple outputs from a set of data, using which()

Tags: r

I have to create a function "character()", that takes in a character's name from the Star Wars data set, and outputs the age, and height of the character. One of the requirements is that I use the "which()" function to find the data.

For example, if I type in character("C-P30"), I need to print "Character C-3P0's age is 1909, species is Droid, and height is 167". I am using the starwars data set from the dyplr package. An example of the data is below:
[starwars data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPsjY.png)

So far I have created variables for the outputs I need:

`height <- which(starwars$height == starwars$name)`
`species <- which(starwars$species == starwars$name)`
`age <- which(2021-starwars$birth_year == starwars$name`

I am unsure how I should create the name variable for the function.

I have attempted to create the the following function, and it has not worked:

`character <- function(starwars,name)`
`sprintf("Character %s's age is %s, species is %s, and height is %s", name, age, species, height)`

Essentially I need the function to work like this:

`character("C-3P0")`

And I need it to respond by printing:

"Character C-3PO's age is 1909, species is Droid, and height is 167"

*The function needs to work for every character, so if I want to see the outputs for "Darth Vader", I need to be able to run:
`character("Darth Vader")`

and I need it to respond by printing
"Character Darth Vader's age is...."

with the age, height, and species outputs...

Any help would be appreciated, I am stuck on this one!

Comment: You insist on using base R functions for your purpose or only which() function is necessary?

Comment: Only the which() function is required, however the goal is to create a function "character()" that works as described.

Answer (score 0):

Ok we don't have a column named `age` in the `starwars` data set but I used `birth_date` instead and I think the following codes work:

```
starwars_finder <- function(name = "C-3PO") {
  height <- starwars$height[which(starwars$name == name)]
  birth_year <- starwars$birth_year[which(starwars$name == name)]
  species <- starwars$species[which(starwars$name == name)]
  message(paste("Character", name, "birthdate is", birth_year, "and the species is", 
                species, "and height is", height))
}

starwars_finder(name = "Chewbacca")

Character Chewbacca birthdata is 200 and the species is Wookiee and height is 228
```

By the way a far better approach would be using tidyeval framework which is the powerhouse behind tidyverse functions:

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

starwars_finder2 <- function(ch_name) {
  ch_name <- rlang::enquo(ch_name)     # We first quote the argument provided by the user from evaluation by using enquo() function
 
 starwars %>%
   filter(name == !!ch_name) %>%      # Then we force evaluate it with !! which is called bang bang operator and this technique is mostly used for the purpose of data masking, where an expression here ch_name is then evaluated in the context of starwars data frame
   select(name, birth_year, species, height) %>%
   mutate(description = glue::glue("The character {name}'s birthdate is {birth_year}, the species is {species}, and the height is {height}")) %>%
   select(description)
}

starwars_finder2(ch_name = "Owen Lars")

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  description                                                                           
  <glue>                                                                                
1 The character Owen Lars's birthdate is 52, the species is Human, and the height is 178
```

For more information just check the following concise [book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/welcome.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, you are correct. For age, I want to take the current year and subtract the characters birth date, to calculate their age in years.

Comment: Your welcome, I just added another solution which I think may be better.